# install.packages omits source files

Tags: r, install.packages

R makes it easy to install a package, e.g.,

```
install.packages("rmarkdown")
```

This works nicely, and concludes remarking

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    â€˜/tmp/Rtmpb9da02/downloaded_packagesâ€™`
```

But after this, the directory `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/R` only contains 3 files: `rmarkdown`, `rmarkdown.rdb`, and `rmarkdown.rdx`.

In contrast, the just downloaded `/tmp/Rtmpb9da02/downloaded_packages/rmarkdown_1.11.tar.gz` would provide the corresponding directory `rmarkdown/R` with the full source files:

```
base64.R                html_vignette.R            render_html.R
beamer_presentation.R   includes.R                 render.R
draft.R                 ioslides_presentation.R    render_site.R
github_document.R       knit_print.R               rtf_document.R
html_dependencies.R     latex_dependencies.R       shiny_module.R
html_document_base.R    list_builder.R             shiny_prerendered.R
html_document.R         md_document.R              shiny.R
html_extras.R           odt_document.R             slidy_presentation.R
html_fragment.R         output_format.R            stack.R
html_notebook_output.R  pandoc.R                   tufte_handout.R
html_notebook.R         params.R                   util.R
html_paged.R            pdf_document.R             word_document.R
html_parser.R           performance.R              zzz.R
html_resource_copy.R    powerpoint_presentation.R
html_resources.R        relative_to.R
```

Why are the sources being withheld?

How should I obtain them?  Besides `tar zxf`, is there a "best practice" approach?  I'm looking for an installation that will allow me to modify one or more source files, re-build the package, and re-load it into my R process.  An added bonus would be hooking up with the source code control system behind the source, e.g., git.

Comment: After you run `install.packages()` can you load it with `library()`?

Comment: R installation does not install source files from the `./R/` directory of the source package. It is much more efficient to load binary already-parsed files than it is to re-parse the files each and every time you call `library`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the source code as you did, modify the R files as you wish and reinstall with:

```
install.packages('/path/to/my_rmarkdown_1.11', repos= NULL, type= 'source')
```